# Return modified generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to modify an object after its creation. I would like to set the properties of this object to -1 for int or string.empty "" for a string. Bellow is a sample code of what I already have.

```
class TestClassAccess{
    public int MyPropInt { get; set { ModifyOnAccessDenied<int>(value); } }
    public string MyPropString { get; set { ModifyOnAccessDenied<string>(value); } }

    public TestClassAccess() { }

    private T ModifyOnAccessDenied<T>(T propertyToChange) {
        var _hasAccess = false; //not really important how this is made
        if (!_hasAccess)
        {
            if (propertyToChange is string)
                propertyToChange = string.Empty;
            else if (propertyToChange is int)
                propertyToChange = -1;
        }            
        return  propertyToChange;
    }
}
```

so.. issues i am having.

1. It doesn't compile as I cannot convert property to change to string or int.
2. I don't knot if i can use set methods like this.
3. Is this possible or am i being to ambitious.

Thank.s
KJ

Comment: I modified my answer with a method to do this with generics. It requires .Net 4.0 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking for specific types in a generic function you are probably doing something wrong.  In this case you can easily just pass in a default value rather than having it hard coded:

```
private T ModifyOnAccessDenied<T>(T newValue, T defaultValue) {
    var _hasAccess = false; //not really important how this is made
    if (!_hasAccess)
    {
        newValue = defaultValue;
    }            
    return newValue;
}
```

I've also renamed `propertyToChange` to `newValue` because what you have in this function is the new value, not a property.

Also your property definitions will not work.  If you need to include any logic in your getter or setting you cannot use the auto-initializer syntax and must implement the property with a backing field.

Comment: yeah you are right it is a much better idea to pass in the default value with the method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a point in making this function generic if it needs specific action for each type. This seems more appropriate.

```
    class TestClassAccess
    {
        public int MyPropInt { get; set { ModifyOnAccessDenied<int>(value); } }
        public string MyPropString { get; set { ModifyOnAccessDenied<string>(value); } }

        public TestClassAccess() { }

        private static volatile bool _hasAccess = false;
        private string ModifyOnAccessDenied<string>(string propertyToChange)
        {
            if (!_hasAccess)
                return string.Empty;
            return propertyToChange;
        }
        private int ModifyOnAccessDenied<int>(int propertyToChange)
        {
            if (!_hasAccess)
                return -1;
            return propertyToChange;
        }
    }
```

You can however do this using dynamics, but this does require .NET 4.0

```
private T ModifyOnAccessDenied<T>(T propertyToChange)
{
    if (!_hasAccess)
    {
        if (propertyToChange is string)
            return (dynamic)string.Empty;
        else if (propertyToChange is int)
            return (dynamic)(int)-1;
    }
    return propertyToChange;
}
```

Fully working sample:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        TestClassAccess test = new TestClassAccess();
        test.MyPropInt = 4;
        test.MyPropString = "TEST";
        Console.WriteLine("MyPropInt {0}, MyPropString '{1}'",test.MyPropInt, test.MyPropString);
        // Prints "MyPropInt -1, MyPropString ''
    }
    class TestClassAccess
    {
        private int myPropInt = 0;
        public int MyPropInt { get { return myPropInt; } set { myPropInt = ModifyOnAccessDenied<int>(value); } }
        private string myPropString = string.Empty;
        public string MyPropString { get { return myPropString; } set { myPropString = ModifyOnAccessDenied<string>(value); } }

        public static volatile bool _hasAccess = false;
        private T ModifyOnAccessDenied<T>(T propertyToChange)
        {
            if (!_hasAccess)
            {
                if (propertyToChange is string)
                    return (dynamic)string.Empty;
                else if (propertyToChange is int)
                    return (dynamic)(int)-1;
            }
            return propertyToChange;
        }
    }
}
```